# How to sort greek letters/symbols JavaScript

Tags: javascript

I have managed to sort an array of objects by element name 'post_api_name' however some of these elements start with a Greek symbol (e.g. α-β Arteether). How can I convert these symbols to be placed alongside 0-9 and not Z+1.

```
RESULT.sort(function(a, b) {
  var textA = a.post_api_name.toUpperCase();
  var textB = b.post_api_name.toUpperCase();
  return (textA < textB) ? -1 : (textA > textB) ? 1 : 0;
});
```

For clarity, the current sorted results show as:

a
b
c
α

I am hoping to achieve:

α
a
b
c

Comment: Do you have some example initial data and the expected result?

Comment: Good point - I have updated my original post.

Comment: Should these Greek letetrs go before or after numbers or any other symbols?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can try sorting using the Greek locale.  You would want to test with more cases as I have no idea what other sorting rules could apply.  Browser support for [localeCompare](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/localeCompare) is still relatively cutting edge (IE11).  Maybe you can find a [poly-fill](https://www.npmjs.com/package/locale-compare-polyfill).

Maybe more preferably you might just have a list of Greek characters that you support and replace them with one of the characters between 9 and A for sorting purposes (:;<=>? or @).

```js
var items = ['a', 'b', 'c', 'α', '9', '4', '1']

items.sort(function(a, b){
  return a.localeCompare(b, 'el');
});

console.log(items);
```

Answer (score 0):

By default, the decimal code for the characters like 'α' will start from 128 i.e they come under extended ASCII codes.

I know there is no particular way of doing this as per your requirement. You can try the below function which will achieve you sorting the normal characters too and puts the greek/additional characters at first.

```
var mySortedChars = [];

function sortMyArray(array) {
    array.forEach(function(val) {
       if (val.charCodeAt(0) > 127) {
          mySortedChars.push(val);
          _.pull(array, val);
       }
    });
    array.sort();
    array.forEach(function(val) {
       mySortedChars.push(val);
    });
    return mySortedChars;
}
```

The above function will return you the sorted characters as per your requirement.

**Note**: `_.pull` is a util from the lodash library. You may have to use your own methods to splice the special characters instead of using `_.pull(array, val);`

Answer (score 0):

A possible solution written in ES6. Split data out into standard and greek starting elements. Sort these results and then concat them.

```js
const greekLower = new Set();
for (let c = 0x3B1; c < 0x3C9; c += 1) {
  greekLower.add(String.fromCodePoint(c));
}
const data = ['xa', 'αb', 'yc', 'βd', 'ae', '1f', 'γg', '9h'];
const standard = [];
const greek = [];
for (let v of data) {
  if (greekLower.has(v.charAt(0).toLowerCase())) {
    greek.push(v);
  } else {
    standard.push(v);
  }
}
standard.sort();
greek.sort();
const sorted = greek.concat(standard);
document.getElementById('out').textContent = JSON.stringify(sorted);
console.log(sorted);
```

```html
<pre id="out"></pre>
```